# Using doctrine instead of sql

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have to following function in my symfony-web-controller:

```
private function findResponsibleDepartment( $suche )
{

    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $arrTerm = explode(" ", $suche);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrTerm); $i++)
    {
        $arrWhere[] = "gs.plz LIKE '" . $arrTerm[$i] . "'";
        //$arrParameter[] = "\"value".$i . "\" => \"%" .$arrTerm[$i]. "%\"";
    }

    $where = implode($arrWhere, " OR ");
    //$param = implode($arrParameter, ",");

    $query = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT nl.email
            FROM MbsNiederlassungBundle:GebietStadt gs
            INNER JOIN MbsNiederlassungBundle:Niederlassung nl WITH nl.id = gs.idNiederlassung
            WHERE '. $where);
    $result = $query->getResult();
    if( count($result) > 0 )
    {
        $email = $result[0]["email"];
        return $email;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to use more the doctrine-statement. How did i have to change the query for doctrine-like?

Or should I better make a custom repository?

Comment: First repository, yes. Then, we are not doing your work, try to create your DQL/Doctrine statements, and if you specific problems, come back with a new question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific case which isn't particular helpfull to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build query with [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('nl.email')
    ->from('MbsNiederlassungBundle:GebietStadt', 'gs')
    ->innerJoin('MbsNiederlassungBundle:Niederlassung', 'nl', 'WITH', 'nl.id = gs.idNiederlassung');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrTerm); $i++) {
    $ph = 'plz' . $i;
    $qb->orWhere('gs.plz LIKE ' . $ph);
    $qb->setParameter($ph, $arrTerm[$i]);
}
```